# Transfer an Access database to Oracle XE

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access

Ok i have made a really big database in MS ACCESS. So i was wondering that instead of writing long, error prone statements in sql. Is there a way to just transfer the database from access to oracle xe ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+%5Bms-access%5D+migration

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Toad or SQLDeveloper? Both seem to have options to import Access table data.

There also seems to be a solution involving Oracle as ODBC connection:

[Importing access data to oracle](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1040494)

Comment: thank you for the link. But now i seem to have another problem. The relations and constraints doesn't seem to get exported.